# Password Encoding/Encryption on ODC connection Strings

Tags: encryption

I'm interested to understand how passwords provided in ODC (Office Data Connection) connection strings are encoded or encrypted.

The format of the connection string is

```
<odc:ConnectionString>Provider=MSOLAP.4;Persist Security Info=True;Data Source=[URL here];Initial Catalog=[catalog name here];User ID=[user id here];Password=[password here];</odc:ConnectionString>
```

The password appears to be base64 encoded but past that I've not yet worked out if it's a hash or encrypted.

Comment: Is it really a password and not a kerberos token?

Comment: based on http://blogs.msdn.com/b/emeadaxsupport/archive/2010/02/17/how-to-manually-deploy-odc-files-to-microsoft-dynamics-ax-2009-enterprise-portal.aspx I don't think so.  If it was kerberos I think it would state it in the connection string..

Comment: No, it's not a kerberos token: these are ephemeral while connection strings are persistent.

Comment: I *think* it's done in exactly the same way as web.config encryption. I can give you links about that one but I'm not certain it is exactly the same (MS being MS, they might have used a different scheme)

Comment: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy%28v=vs.140%29.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.rsaprotectedconfigurationprovider%28v=vs.100%29.aspx